# Scala value id is not a member of type parameter Field

Tags: scala, typeerror

I declared the case class `Field` and the `Enumeration FieldStatus` with the mutable parameters id and fieldStatus.

```
object FieldStatus extends Enumeration {
  type FieldStatus = Value
  val Empty, Black, White = Value
}

case class Field(var id: Int, var fieldStatus: FieldStatus) {
  def changeFieldStatus(fieldStatus: FieldStatus) : Field = copy(id, fieldStatus)
}
```

In my second case class `Gameboard`, i've implemented a method to `set` the fieldStatus of one `Field`. The `Gameboard` saves the `Field`s in the `vertexList: MutableList[Field]`.
The method `set` just should change the `fieldStatus` of the selected `Field`.

```
case class Gameboard[Field](vertexList: mutable.MutableList[Field], neigh: mutable.MutableList[Edge[Field]])
extends Graph[Field] {
  def set(field: Int, fieldStatus: String): Gameboard[Field] = {
    val fieldtoChange: Option[Field] = vertexList.get(field)
    fieldtoChange match {
      case Some(f) => {
        fieldStatus match {
          case "Black" => f.changeFieldStatus(FieldStatus.Black)
          case "White" => f.changeFieldStatus(FieldStatus.White)
          case "Empty" => f.changeFieldStatus(FieldStatus.Empty)
        }
      }
      case None => println("Field not found on this Gameboard!")
    }
    copy(vertexList, neigh)
  }
}
```

The compiler just throws me this Error:

```
Error:(54, 29) value changeFieldStatus is not a member of type parameter Field
      case "Black" => f.changeFieldStatus(FieldStatus.Black)
```

I also tried to access the member variables of the case class `Field` ... same Error. Did I misunderstand the case class? The [scala-docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) didnt help me there.

Comment: `fieldStatus` is a `String`, but your method `changeFieldStatus` is receiving a `FieldStatus`, I think that is the problem.

Comment: oh yeah thats true. But I cant acces the variables id and fieldStatus from Field too. I thought this is the same problem

Comment: Could you post what `FieldStatus` is? show the code. And `vertexList` what is? a `List`. 

I Think you still are having the same problem, you are trying yo pass a `FieldStatus.Black` to your method, but your method receives a `FieldStatus`, not a `FieldStatus.Black`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `Field` type parameter to Gameboard is shadowing the case class of the same name. Some possible solutions:

1. Drop the type parameter and just write it as `case class Gameboard(...) extends Graph[Field]`, unless you're actually planning on having different kinds of fields. I suspect this is the solution you want in your case.
2. Rename the type parameter and add Field as an upper bound, i.e.: `class Gameboard[F <: Field]`.